# Animate scrolling images with random delay (one after another) and random horizontal position

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a list of x images. For each image I create an UIImageView with y the view height and an random x

```
func computeImageFrame() -> CGRect {
    let imageWidth: CGFloat = 91
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = 131

    var x = xPos()
    let y = yPos()

    if (x > ((self.backgroundView?.bounds.width)! - (self.backgroundView?.bounds.width)! * 0.20)){
        x = x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: ((self.backgroundView?.bounds.width)! - (self.backgroundView?.bounds.width)! * 0.20))}

    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
}
```

where

```
func xPos() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((self.backgroundView?.frame.size.width)!)))
}
func yPos() -> CGFloat {
    return self.backgroundView.bounds.height
}
```

At this point, I have a list on UIImageViews where x is random and y is viewHeight and now I'm trying to animate

```
func animateBackgroundFor(_ imageViews: [UIImageView]) {
    for imageView in imageViews {
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    // Animate background
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, delay: 0.0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear], animations: {
        for imageView in imageViews {
            imageView.frame = imageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -7 * imageView.frame.size.height)
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

My question is how can I get them to shoot one after another, instead of at the same time, and how can I recompute each image's horizontal position at every loop.

Thank you

Edit: forgot to mention, I have tried

```
func animateBackgroundFor(_ imageViews: [UIImageView]) {
    for imageView in imageViews {
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    for imageView in imageViews {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, delay: 1.2, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear], animations: {
            imageView.frame = imageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -7 * imageView.frame.size.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following solution.
Add to your controller private property:

`private var imageViews = [UIImageView]()`

and then modify your `animateBackgroundFor(_)` method in a such way:

```
func animateBackgroundFor(_ imageViews: [UIImageView]) {
    for imageView in imageViews {
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    self.imageViews = imageViews
    animateImage(at: 0)
}

func animateImage(at index: NSInteger) {
    guard index >= 0 && index < imageViews.count else { return }
    let imageView = imageViews[index]
    imageView.frame = computeImageFrame()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear,
                   animations: { 
                    imageView.frame = imageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -7 * imageView.frame.size.height)
    },
                   completion: {
        [weak self] finished in
                    guard finished && self != nil else { return }
                    let nextIndex = index + 1 < self!.imageViews.count ? index + 1 : 0
                    self!.animateImage(at: nextIndex)
    })
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!